# Indicator functions vs. conditions

Tags: statistics, notation

I'm trying to understand theorem 2.1 of the following paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.5863.pdf. It's a statistics paper, and since I'm coming from a physics background, understanding the notation is hard.

The crux of my current issue can be seen from the numerator of the RHS of Eq. 2.1:

$\mathcal{E}\{|\mathrm{det}\nabla^2f(t_0)|\mathcal{I}_{\{f(t_0)>u\}}\mathcal{I}_{\{\mathrm{index(\nabla^2f(t_0))=N\}}}|\nabla f(t_0)=0\}$

(I'm using $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{I}$ for the script E and 1 that the paper used because I don't know how to render those scripts. If anyone can help with that I'll amend this.)

Two issues:

1) I understand expressions of the type $f(x|y)$ to mean the value of $f(x)$, given that $y$ is true. However these expressions only have one |. There are three |'s in the above. The only way I can see to reconcile this is that the first two |'s (around the determinant) are absolute value signs. Am I correct?

2) According to Wikipedia, the indicator functions mean that if the condition is met, the value is 1, otherwise it's 0. So in this case, $\mathcal{I}_{\{f(t_0)>u\}} = 1$ if $f(t_0)>u$, and $0$ otherwise. However if this is the case, why can't we simply take $f(t_0)>u$ to be a condition? After all, if the condition isn't met, the expression is zero.

In other words, can I say

$\mathcal{E}\{|\mathrm{det}\nabla^2f(t_0)|\mathcal{I}_{\{f(t_0)>u\}}\mathcal{I}_{\{\mathrm{index(\nabla^2f(t_0))=N\}}}|\nabla f(t_0)=0\} = \mathcal{E}\{|\mathrm{det}\nabla^2f(t_0)||\nabla f(t_0)=0,f(t_0)>u,\mathrm{index}(\nabla^2f(t_0))=N\}$

The obvious answer appears to be "no" since otherwise the author would've written it as such, but I don't see why.

Comment: The first two $\vert$ are an absolute value. You can's push the indicators function in the condition, because you are taking the expectation of something. Zero values count in the computation. If you consider only positive values, the expectation will mechanically be higher.